# Insert multiple data at once

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, multiple-insert

Though there are some same questions here, still I want to post my own question as I think I made a solution, but it's not working. Here is the following code:

```
$i=1;
while ( $i<= 10) 
{
    $i++;
    $sql    =   "INSERT INTO job (Category, Title, Type) VALUES ('$_POST[cat]','$_POST[title]','$_POST[type]')";
}
```

Shouldn't it insert 10 data one by one? But it just inserts 1 data. Why is this happening?

Comment: you are inserting the same thing 10 times

Comment: Probably a unique column. Check your SQL errors.

Comment: Yes I want to. @raheelshan

Comment: `echo $sql;` and then copy it in phpmyadmin more than once, see what errors you get

Comment: Yes I have a auto increment primary column named ID. But how could be it a problem? There is no SQL error show up. @WayneWhitty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that you're constructing exactly the same sql string every iteration.
Your code should be:

 `$i=1;`
 `while ( $i<= 10)`
 `{`
    `$i++;`
    `$sql    =   "INSERT INTO job (Category, Title, Type)`
                 `VALUES ('{$_POST[cat]}','{$_POST[title]}','{$_POST[type]}')";`
    `mysql_query($sql);`
 `}`

Pay attention to the `[]`

Answer (score 3):

You don't insert anything in this code, just assign a value to the string `$sql` (and overwrite it 10 times). I guess you execute the query *after* the while-loop.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you are calling `mysqli_query($conn, $query)` only once,
put it inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I do it to insert multiple results

```
$sql = "INSERT  INTO job(category,title,type) VALUES";
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($category);$i++)
{
   if($i= sizeof($category) - 1)
    $sql. = "(".$category[$i].",".$title[$i].",".$type[$i].");"; 
   else
    $sql. = "(".$category[$i].",".$title[$i].",".$type[$i]."),"; 
}
 $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Considering `$category,$title,$type` as arrays which you want to insert in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi("host","user","pass","db_name");

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
  $sql = "INSERT INTO job (Category, Title, Type)
          VALUES ('" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['cat']) . "','" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['title']) . "','" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['type']) . "')";
  $mysqli->query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$i=1;
$addCount=0;
while ( $i<= 10) 
{
    $i++;
    $sql    =   "INSERT INTO job (Category, Title, Type) VALUES ('$_POST[cat]','$_POST[title]','$_POST[type]')";
    if(mysql_query($sql)){
        $addCount++;
    }
}

echo "Total number of records added: ".$addCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this. Instead of running 10 queries
you can do it with single query

```
$i=1;

while ( $i<= 10) 
{
    $i++;
    $values[]       =   "('$_POST[cat]','$_POST[title]','$_POST[type]')";
}
$new_values =   implode(',',$values);
$sql    =   "INSERT INTO job (Category, Title, Type) VALUES $new_values";
```

And now you can use mysqli_query to run it.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Do As Like Following...

```
 $i=1;
 while ( $i<= 10) {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO job (Category, Title, Type) VALUES('".$_POST[cat]."','".$_POST[title]."','".$_POST[type]."')");
   $i++;
}
```